# Difficulties on creating a jQuery accordion plugin (Super Neat!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am creating a jQuery accordion plugin for personal use.

**My main goal is having a super-duper neat JS code and HTML stracture.**

This is how far I made it
http://jsfiddle.net/QA2eH/

HTML Stracture:

```
<div class="accordion">

    <div class="accordion-wrapper">
        <div class="accordion-toggle">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Mea regione persecuti ne. suscipi one antur duo ne, elitr voluptua conceptam at eam</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-wrapper">
        <div class="accordion-toggle">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Mea regione persecuti ne. suscipi one antur duo ne, elitr voluptua conceptam at eam</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-wrapper">
        <div class="accordion-toggle">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Mea regione persecuti ne. suscipi one antur duo ne, elitr voluptua conceptam at eam</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

JS Code(Obv not done yet)

```
$(function(){
        $('.accordion .accordion-wrapper .accordion-toggle').on('click',function(){
            $(this).next('.content').slideDown(300).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        });
});
```

**Quick summary:**
Using parent and siblings functions, clicking on a toggle will add its wrapper a class name **.active**, and will remove this class name from the rest of the wrappers.

**What I can't do:**

SlideUp/hide the contents inside all the wrappers that are not ".active"

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why reinvent the wheel? Bootstrap does this, it's VERY widely adopted?

Comment: Hi r3mus, I am already using the bootstrap framework. But it's way less flexible than what I am trying to achieve here. Edit: One of the problems is that you can't access the title of an active title. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.accordion .accordion-wrapper .accordion-toggle').on('click', function () {
        $(this)
        .next('.content')
        .slideDown(300)
        .parent()
        .addClass('active')
        .siblings()
        .removeClass('active')
        .find('.content')
        .slideUp(300);
    });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ACfyu/)

I added `.find('.content')` and `.slideUp(300);` to your chain.

Comment: Your code seems to work perfect. Also, I will look into the Find function. Thank you Sergio.

Comment: If I may ask one more question. How can I close an opened accordion?

Comment: @user3121234, you are using slideDown/Up for that so you can use the same. You could also use (which is better) CSS transitions, will update my answer with that.

Comment: @user3121234, actually with CSS transitions there are limitations to the height. Use `$('.accordion .content').slideUp(300);` if you want to close them all.

Comment: Well, SlideUp/Down works pretty smooth. About closing an opened accordion, I just replaced "SlideDown" with slideToggle, and I think it's ready to use now. Thanks Sergio, I appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

You should program using small functions so you can reuse them in many more cases, for example in you case, you can do this:

```
$(function(){
    // Asociate toggleContents function to element click
    $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', toggleContents);

    function toggleContents (event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        hideContents($this);
        showContents($this);
    }

    function showContents ($obj) {
        //We show the contents, using dequeue, for fixing queues on mutliple user clicks
        $('.content', $obj.parent())
            .addClass('active')
            .slideDown(300)
            .dequeue();
    }

    function hideContents ($obj) {
        $('.active.content', $obj.parents('.accordion'))
            .removeClass('.active')
            .slideUp(300)
            .dequeue();
    }
});
```

Comment: The thing is that I'm not going to use it this wide that I need to write it that way. Of course, using your way is WAY better and way more flexible but I'm looking for something really simple. Thank you!